# Применить стили th c colspan к td

Tags: html, css, css3

У меня есть таблица, в которой `<th>` имеет `colspan`, и где границы `<th>` отмечены черной линией:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th colspan="2">vote 1</th>
    <th colspan="4">vote 2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>vote1</td>
      <td>vote1</td>
      <td>vote2</td>
      <td>vote2</td>
      <td>vote2</td>
      <td>vote2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Мне бы хотелось, чтобы эти границы также отмечались и у `<td>`, `first` и `last` не подходят, если несколько `<th>` с `colspan`. Более подробный рисунок таблицы смотрите на рисунке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно отметить границы первого и последнего `<td>` относящегося к родительскому `<th>`. Таблица генерируется динамически, в зависимости от данных.

Comment: А разметку мы сами должны придумать?

Comment: @Cheg, если ты придумаешь больше одного (принципиально разных) вариантов разметки table, я очень удивлюсь.

Comment: @Cheg если тебе это поможет - я выложил. мне нужно отметить границы td первого и последнего относящегося к родительскому th

Comment: @Qwertiy я имел ввиду конкретно данную таблицу (сверстанную, с css), на основе которой и нужно решить проблему

Comment: @Cheg моя таблица динамически генерируется в зависимости от данных и там используется код серверного языка, чтобы добиться такой красоты, поэтому мне хочется избавиться от условий во вьюхе. Например при создании данной таблицы я проверяю первый элемент в цикле или последний и в зависимости от этого присваиваю класс и  css добавляю стиль

Comment: Если мы заведомо знаем, что у нас первые 2 смежные и последние 4, то что мешает сделать td:first-child, td:nth-child(3) { border-left: 1px solid black; } td:nth-child(2), td:last-child { border-right: 1px solid black; } ?

Comment: @MedvedevDev проблема  том что мы не знаем сколько смежных колонок. Это я для примера привел. Сколько смежных зависит от данных  бд

Comment: @Maga Andiskiy, тогда, думается мне, одним css'ом не обойтись.

Answer (score 1):

Не смотря на давность вопроса, ответ на него так и не дали. Тем временем, на просторах сети проблема актуальна до сих пор.

После поисков и экспериментов, пришёл к выводу, что самым простым и надёжным решением будет использование псевдоэлемента с абсолютным позиционированием и нужными стилями.

- Исходим из того, что ячеек-заголовков Vote 1 и Vote 2, группирующих *неопределённое* количество подзаголовков, всегда два и они всегда крайние справа. Тогда задаём Vote 1 и Vote 2 `position: relative;`, а псевдоэлементам (`::after`) в этих ячейках - `position: absolute;`.
- Т.к. количество строк заранее неизвестно, то выставляем с запасом минимальную высоту для псевдоэлемента (`min-height: 100vh;`), при этом обрезаем лишнее с помощью `table { overflow: hidden; }`.
- По ширине растягиваем псевдоэлемент на 100%, охватывая таким образом все ячейки находящиеся ниже, которые перекрывает `<th colspan="">`.
- Чтобы псевдоэлемент позволял взаимодействовать с содержимым ячеек, добавляем свойство `pointer-events: none;`.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 2px #222;
  font: 14px/1em sans-serif;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
th, td {
  min-width: 2em;
  padding: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
th { box-shadow: inset 1px -2px 0px 0px #ccc; }
td { box-shadow: inset 1px -1px 0px 0px #ccc; }
td:not(:first-of-type) { text-align: center; }

tr:first-of-type > th:nth-last-of-type(1),
tr:first-of-type > th:nth-last-of-type(2) {
  position: relative;
}
tr:first-of-type > th:nth-last-of-type(1)::after,
tr:first-of-type > th:nth-last-of-type(2)::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 3px 0 0px -1px #222;
  pointer-events: none;
}

td button {
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font: 14px/0.75em sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2"><input type="search"></th>
      <th rowspan="2">Prop. Rep.</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Meet. Vote Rec'd</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Proxy Rec'd</th>
      <th colspan="2">Vote 1</th>
      <th colspan="4">Vote 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Test in 5</th>
      <th>Custom</th>
      <th>yes</th>
      <th>no</th>
      <th>don't know</th>
      <th>Custom</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>14 Elm St</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><button>+</button></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><button>+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>15 Elm St</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><button>+</button></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><button>+</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно применить [colgroup](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup)

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 2px #222;
  font: 14px/1em sans-serif;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
th, td {
  min-width: 2em;
  padding: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
th { box-shadow: inset 1px -2px 0px 0px #ccc; }
td { box-shadow: inset 1px -1px 0px 0px #ccc; }

td button {
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font: 14px/0.75em sans-serif;
}

colgroup {
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col span="4"/>
  </colgroup>
  <colgroup>
    <col span="2" />
  </colgroup>
  <colgroup>
    <col span="4" />
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2"><input type="search"></th>
      <th rowspan="2">Prop. Rep.</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Meet. Vote Rec'd</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Proxy Rec'd</th>
      <th colspan="2">Vote 1</th>
      <th colspan="4">Vote 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Test in 5</th>
      <th>Custom</th>
      <th>yes</th>
      <th>no</th>
      <th>don't know</th>
      <th>Custom</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>14 Elm St</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><button>+</button></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><button>+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>15 Elm St</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><button>+</button></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><button>+</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```